# Election forensics using statistical methods in practice?

Tags: application, fraud-detection

Are you aware of any examples of election forensics in practice? Or at least any applied research on real large-scale datasets (e.g. govermental elections)? Thanks.

Comment: http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/elections/election2000/butterfly.review.pdf - Wouldn't consider it "applied" research, but may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Walter Mebane (University of Michigan) has written a lot on using Benford's Law distributions of digits as tests for electoral fraud, both as a methods problem and in a series of applications.  There are several working papers listed here: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wmebane/

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google led to [a paper by Cantu and Saiegh on Argentinian elections](http://extranet.isnie.org/uploads/isnie2011/saiegh_cantu.pdf), which appears to have some good references as well. The website [FiveThirtyEight](http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/) does a lot of election prediction and perhaps has some good links. And I seem to remember Andrew Gelman doing some forensics work, but couldn't find a link.